# Program external F5529 with Energia via LaunchPad

Tags: msp430, jtag

I have a LaunchPad (Rev 1.6 MSP-EXP430F5529LP) that I am using as a programmer for an external MSP430F5529 chip. The programming is done via Spy-By-Wire(see picture below for setup).

The programming works fine via CCS, there are no issues coding or debugging.

I tried to program the external chip via Energia. The programming seems to complete successfully, however, none of the code seems to be running.

Any insight as to what I may be doing wrong, or any additional setup steps? Or..is what I'm trying to do not possible?

[image: Setup]

Comment: The LaunchPad does not support JTAG. I guess you mean Spy-Bi-Wire? Anyway, does Energia work with the LaunchPad's F5529?

Comment: Yes, I can program the (red above) LaunchPad F5529 with Energia without a problem when the jumpers are connected. Yes, I did mean Spy-Bi-Wire.

Comment: In theory, Energia should not even notice that there is a different MCU. What is your Energia program? Does a simple LED blinky work?

Comment: It does not work on my custom PCB, but it does work if it program the launchpad.

Comment: Apparently, your code or Energia's code uses some hardware that exists only on the LaunchPad. Please show a [mcve].